# Can you bound $2^n$ by n!

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the powerset of N
$(1), (2), (1,2), (3), (1,3), (2,3), (1,2,3), (4), ...$
Map this to 
$(2), (3), (2,3), (5), (2,5), (3,5), (2,3,5), (7), ...$
Where n is replaced by the nth prime
If we then multiply all the primes
$(2), (3), (6), (5), (10), (15), (30), (7), ...$
We get a sequence whose range grows factorially. How can the continuum which is of the order 2^n outweigh n factorial?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Answering the title question- $1\times 2\times3\times4 = 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 2 > 2^4$ and the difference gets bigger for larger $n$. For smaller $n$,
\begin{align}0! =  1 = 2^0\\ 1! = 1 < 2^1\\ 2! = 2 < 2^2 \\ 3!=6<2^3\end{align}

Comment: Yea I’m just wondering why 2^n is such a big deal if we can go to n!

Answer (score 2):

What you have shown is a bijection between *finite* subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and squarefree natural numbers. If you're asking whether this construction contradicts Cantor, it does not: you are missing almost all elements of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ (the infinite subsets) so you have not proven that the power set of the natural numbers is countable.

I don't really understand what you mean about one set "outweighing" the other, though---both are (countably) infinite.